# Why won't my gif cycle when i try to remove the background in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, web, gif

For the project I'm working on I need to make a gif without a background. I tried saving before deleting the background and it works fine. However, when I use the magic wand tool to select the background and delete it from each layer the gif won't work when I try saving it for web.

Answer (score 0):

When saving, make sure the 'Preset' is set to one of the GIF options. Ensure that the box for transparency IS ticked.